# How IEnumerable<T> interface has ToList() Method

Tags: linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

My Code:

```
internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
{
   IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
   return query.ToList();
}
```

As you can see above we are calling ToList() method. When I go into IQueryable, I have seen that it gets inheritence from IEnumerable but in IEnumerable I can not see any ToList() method. Where and how this method comes from? Can you help me please.

Comment: Where are you looking? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0

Answer (score 4):

The extension methods provided for `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are generally respectively found in the types `Queryable` and `Enumerable`.

Keep in mind that the former are interfaces. Interfaces can't have implementations defined. These are extension methods (*with* implementation) which means they need to be defined in a `static class` as `static` methods.

- [`Queryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.100).aspx) [MSDN]
- [`Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) [MSDN]
- [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) [MSDN]

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. The people who are curious about extension methods this link has useful information : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709310/Extension-Method-In-Csharp